# laravel ajax store and update data

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I use ajax to store and update some data in DB, 
it works when I store some data but when I remove comment from code to update some data i got the `500 Internal error` .

```
public function update(Request $request){
        $newRecord = new AllAttendanceData;
        $newRecord -> studentId = $request->id;
        $newRecord -> studentState = $request->state;
        $newRecord ->save();
        $state = $request->state;
        $id = $request->id;
        $editStuState = StuAtt::first();
        // if ( $state == 1) {
        //  $editStuState -> present +=1;
        // }elseif ($state == 2) {
        //  $editStuState -> leave +=1;
        // }else{
        //  $editStuState -> absent +=1;            
        // }
        // $editStuState ->save();
    return response($state );
    }
```

and my ajax code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
           $state = this.value;
           $id = $(this).attr('id')
           $.ajax({
         type: "get",
        url: '/singleAttData/',
        data: { state:$state ,id: $id}, 
        success: function(result) {
            window.console.log('Successful:'+result[0]);
        }
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

any one has solution?

Comment: What does `StuAtt::first();` give you? If it's undefined the rest of the code will fail. Try it out in php artisan tinker, see what you get from there. Do you get the console.log from the response?

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, open 'Developer Tools', go to 'Network' and select your Ajax request. Click the 'Response' tab and you will see why the failure is occurring.

Also, make sure to validate your input, even on Ajax requests.